# How to add a spinner when the video is loading? with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a custom player and I need to know how I can add a spinner to it. The code is from another guy, but in the tutorial he didn't show how to do a loading spinner, and now I don't know how I can create with java.

I've tried this (Javascript):

```
video.on("waiting", function ()
{
    this.addClass("video-custom-waiting");
});
video.on("playing", function ()
{
    this.removeClass("video-custom-waiting");
});
```

but didn't work, it still show the spinner even with this code. maybe this code doesn't work in my case, i don't know.

I created a div with the class `spinner`, and put the classes like this:

```
.video-custom-waiting .spinner{
display:block;
}
.spinner{
position:absolute;
top:48%;
left:48%;
display:none;
border:8px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1);
border-left-color:red;
height:60px;
width:60px;
border-radius:50%;
animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
z-index:999;
}
```

Video-custom-waiting is designed to hide the spinner when the video finishes loading, but as you can see, it's not working.

How can i fix it? and how a use the spinner when the video is pause for load, when for example an user jump for a part of the video and he need load this part?

html part.

This is the div spinner, the spinner that i want put on the player
 `<div class="spinner"></div>`

And my video code:

```
<video controls class="video" id="video"  autoplay disablepictureinpicture tabindex="-1" >
```

Comment: `this.removeClass(video-custom-waiting")` should be `this.removeClass("video-custom-waiting")`

Comment: I'm sorry to have put it like this here, but in the script is correct

Comment: What are you applying/removing the class `video-custom-waiting` to and from?

Comment: the div spinner. from the video player

Comment: i need hide it when the video is playing, and show when the video is loading

Comment: Without being able to see the full code or HTML markup it is hard to tell but within the various callbacks I would assume ( and likely incorrectly ) that `this` referred to the actual video Object??

Comment: so, i can put the html code in the question, if you want. But `this` i don't know tell you what exactly is. isn't my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const video = document.querySelector('video');

video.onwaiting = (event) => {
  console.log('Video is waiting for more data.');
};
```

Answer (score 2):

use this and set the top and left according to requirements.

```js
var video = document.getElementById("video");
        video.onwaiting = function(){
            document.getElementById("spinner").style.display="block"
        }
```

```css
.main{
            height: fit-content;
            width: fit-content;
        }
        .spinner{
            position:absolute;
            top:100px;
            left:100px;
            display:none;
            border:8px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1);
            border-left-color:red;
            height:60px;
            width:60px;
            border-radius:50%;
            z-index:999;
            animation: rotate linear 2s infinite;
            animation-delay: 0ms;
        }
        @keyframes rotate{
            from{
                transform: rotateZ(0deg);
            }
            to{
                transform: rotateZ(360deg);
            }
        }
```

```html
 <section class="main">
    <video controls width="300" height="300" class="video" id="video" autoplay disablepictureinpicture tabindex="-1">
        <source src="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1rAHEQPrg1nY0xC3Q0UgVuqSgVWvFiY0a" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <div class="spinner" id="spinner">
    </div>
    </section>
```